# In The Mandalorian S1 E6 The Prisoner, why did the prison ship leave hyperspace?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

Why would the prison ship go to sublight engines, when hyperspace is much faster? Is it just something to put under plot armor or such?

Comment: I don't know if this is still canon, but I believe it used to be the case that remaining in hyperspace requires a ship to expend energy, while remaining in normal space didn't.

Comment: It's not clear why it's in sublight. Given that it's a *transport*, presumably it has recently picked up or dropped off a prisoner and is returning to a set of designated coordinates before safely jumping back to hyperspace on its way to its next programmed stop. For the record, there's no indication why in the official episode guide or the junior novelisation.

Comment: @Cadence, yes it expends fuel, but only because its moving at FTL speeds.

Comment: @Valorum, your idea is probably what the answer was, given they had a certain amount of time to do the mission.

Comment: @BlueSkinandGlowingRedEyes - I can't find a scrap of evidence one way or another, though.

Comment: @Valorum, that’s the most annoying things about these sort of things isn’t it? It just ends up being one of those things that don’t get explained.

Comment: @BlueSkinandGlowingRedEyes - Patience is a virtue. The new *Star Wars: Battles that Changed the Galaxy* allowed me to answer [23 old questions in one fell swoop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Battles+that+Changed+the+Galaxy%22)

Comment: I just had a theory, could the Razor Crest be jamming the Navi computer or something along those lines?

Comment: That wouldn't work to pull it out of hyperspace. Those signals travel at the speed of light, so, by the same principle as the whole "you can't track through hyperspace" thing (which was overturned by the Sequel Trilogy, but that came later), the signals would have been slower than the transport's FTL hyperspace travel and would not have reached it. It would have had to already been out of hyperspace.

Answer (score 1):

The ship didn't leave hyperspace. When Mayfield contacted the Mandalorian, he said that the prisoner is being moved to the ship, so the ship is waiting in space when the prisoner arrives at the ship.

Mayfield also said that they have a limited window until the ship jumps into hyperspace; the ship could use his hyperdrive but must wait for some reason.

Comment: "*for some reason*" is literally the point of this question. What is that reason?

Comment: Additionally, who’s the prisoner in question. The Twi’lek (one brought to the space station) was already locked up, and there was never anyone being transferred in the entirety of the episode.

Comment: Yeah, the prisoner is the Twi’lek brought to the space station is the prisoner. Mayfield say that he is being moved to the ship so in the time they are speaking he just arrive into the prisoner ship.  The reason the ship needs to stop is unknown but the frame for the question is  incorrect. The ship is waiting in the space until the prisoner arrives and the characters have a little window of time until the ship jump into hyperspace, the question seem to infer that the ship don´t go into hyperspace for some reason but the thing we don´t know is why the ship don´t jump when the prisoner arrives.